# delete files downloaded by outlines python library

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, mistral-7b

```
import outlines
model = outlines.models.transformers('mistralai/Mistal-7B-v0.1')
```

I had run the above code on my m1 macbook to try mistral llm, because of that 16 GB size of weights were downloaded on my system. Now I cant find where they were downloaded. I need to delete those files from system to free up my space. Please help me locate those files. Uninstalling the library also didnt help free up my space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be downloaded to the directory `~/.cache/huggingface/hub`.

You can run `cd ~/.cache/huggingface/hub` in the terminal to change to this directory, or run `open ~/.cache/huggingface/hub` to open Finder in this directory.

Versions used: OSX 13.6.1, Python 3.10.10, outlines 0.0.32, and transformers 4.37.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following script in terminal to find out where the large files go

```bash
du -sh -- * | sort -rh
```

Comment: it will take too much time to run. I need a quickest way to see top 20 files by size

Comment: `du -sh -- * | sort -rh | head -20` to list the first 20 lines. However it takes time to compute.